# Default Oozie options in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, oozie

I'm using latest Cloudera cdh4.
By default all default parameters of oozie are in /etc/oozie/conf/oozie-default.xml

I have changed oozie.service.CoordMaterializeTriggerService.lookup.interval to 30:

```
<property>
    <name>oozie.service.CoordMaterializeTriggerService.lookup.interval</name>
    <value>30</value>
</property>
```

Next Cluster was restarted.
But in Hue UI in oozie config I see

```
oozie.service.CoordMaterializeTriggerService.lookup.interval    300
```

Why it happens? And how i can change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override the property in /etc/oozie/conf/oozie-site.xml.

If using CM, you should put it in the Oozie [Safety Valve](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CM4Free/4.5.4/Cloudera-Manager-Free-Edition-User-Guide/cmfeug_topic_5_3.html#topic_5_3_1_unique_1__title_85_unique_5).

And restart Oozie in both cases.

Comment: It has helped. Thanks for answer.